# Unable to get params from axios post request in Django view

Tags: django, django-views, axios

I am currently sending an axios POST request like this from a react frontend to a Django backend

```
const data = {
   'username': username,
   'first_name': first_name,
   'last_name': last_name,
   'email': email,
   'password1': password1,
   'password2': password2,
}
const user_response = axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_URL + '/users/create', data);
```

and attempting to get get these parameters in a Django view like so:

```
class create_user(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print('request: ', request.POST)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However, this returns an empty dictionary.

```
request:  <QueryDict: {}>
```

How do I successfully get the POST request parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you are in a Django REST Framework view, you should use `request.data`